# How to set the data range for palette to map out color in gnuplot

Tags: data-visualisation, chart-design, gnuplot

I am using [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info). I would like to compare across different settings of the same type of data in a color plot using something like the following:

`plot 'pdratio' using 1:2:(abs($1)>0.3?$4:1/0) with p ps 0.75 pt 4 palette`

Gnuplot automatically chooses the data range for the palette to map out color, which can be different from case to case. Is there a way to ask gnuplot to map out colors for the same data range consistently across different cases?

Something like `set palette maxcolor 100` would not be adequate for my purposes.

Comment: you guys seem to have a lot of time dealing with these formatting/wording details, which is good for people to catch the questions quick. I had got a solution, can I answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `cbrange`

> The set **cbrange** command sets the range of values which are colored
>   using the current palette [docs_4.2](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node325.html)

```
set cbrange [min:max]
```

An example of its use can be found on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666134/gnuplot-cbrange-setting)

```
set palette defined (-1 "red", 0 "white", 1 "blue)
ub = 1
lb = -ub
set cbrange [lb:ub]
```

Comment: Your supposed to write reasonably explaining answers... And unless you have a picture you most likely have failed also... But maybe not in this case.

Comment: what about a self-explaining answer like the one I just posted?

Comment: Its rarely self explaining if its just a sentence. But again this may be a exception. altough you can introduce your onneliner in more than 0 letters.